# Symfony service container - use factory with arguments as argument

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, yaml

I have a model which will return a Group valueobject depending on the UID passed to it. This model also contains constants for group UIDs.

```
<?php
namespace V2\Models\Config;

class Groups
{
    const UID_A = 'A';
    const UID_B = 'B';
    const UID_C = 'C';
    const UID_D = 'D';
    const UID_E = 'E';

    /** @var \X\Group\Group */
    private $group;

    public function __construct(\X\Group\Group $group)
    {
        $this->group = $group;
    }

    public function getGroup(string $uid): \X\Core\ValueObject\Group
    {
        return $this->group->getByUid($uid);
    }
}
```

I wish to inject group VOs into services as an argument, the service I wish to inject a group into looks like:

```
  v2.spencer.doc_control.revision.validator:
    class: X\DocControl\Revision\Validator
    autowire: true
    arguments:
      $referenceValidator: '@v2.x.doc_control.revision.reference.validator'
      $privateDocsGroup: '?'
```

I want to inject the group VO returned from the factory Groups::getGroup(uid) passed a specific UID from within the above arguments definitions, for example (this doesn't work, but hopefully gets my intentions across)

```
$privateDocsGroup: '@v2.groups:getGroup(!php/const:V2\Models\Groups::UID_C)'
// or perhaps

arguments:
  $privateDocsGroup:
    factory: 'v2.groups:getGroup'
    arguments:
      $uid: !php/const:V2\Models\Groups::UID_C
```

Is this possible, or do I have to define services for each individual group VO returned from the Factory (I appreciate I could just set up a service for every group VO and inject that in, but that seems like a lot of configuration)?